# Is filing a CV useful, even if not having accumulated reputation yet?

Tags: support, cv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much reputation do you need to be worth using Careers.Stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28938/how-much-reputation-do-you-need-to-be-worth-using-careers-stackoverflow-com)

I'm a new user and just signed up to Stack Overflow, after I discovered jobs.stackoverflow.com today through Joel Spolsky's blog today.

Now I'm wondering whether filing a CV is *only* useful if one is also an active Stack Overflow user, who has positive "karma" (reputation) already? Would a new user turn up in search results by employers at all? Or is it shown, just with zero points?

Or does the CV turn up anyway, when possible employers search by location or keywords, and doesn't necessarily look negative?

Answer (score 1):

I filled in and listed my CV publicly, even though I only had 55 stackoverflow points at the time. I  now have 205 or so.  I wasn't looking for a job then, and I'm not looking for a job now.  Part of my thinking is that it just can't hurt to have stuff online about you, especially that you control.

I don't have the patience for blogging (though I may yet try again), but I'm pretty consistent about using things like linkedin, stackoverflow, serverfault, and now careers.stackoverflow.

Think of it as a free CV editing and hosting service if nothing more.

And, there's nothing more motivating to put yourself out there on stackoverflow than having your CV point at your score.  ;)  It's a net positive.

Answer (score 1):

**Go ahead and sign up, employers will still be interested**

I did a search and contacted at least two people who had just signed up.

BTW, we're still soliciting for this job, if anyone is interested in writing software for making movies:

> http://jobs.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?5746

Comment: Wow. When I was younger I always wanted to work at Pixar, it was kind of a late childhood dream. It's just a shame you are based in America. (Also, my language background is wrong for that particular position)

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome!

Second, if you're new, you're starting with a clean slate. When an employer looks at your profile and sees you signed-up 2 days ago, it's obvious that you can't have community recognition yet :)

Some of us have been here since the very early parts of the private beta, or public beta, and have had, therefore, a lot of time to have earned reputation in the community.

But since the community is fully open, and everyone has euqal opportunity to answer new questions (or old ones), and be recognized, you're coming at a good time, I think.