# Role of reputation in Jobs

Tags: discussion, jobs

I am curious to know how much having high rep helps in getting a good job. Does it even play a role or it's just only for one's own satisfaction?

I joined Stack Exchange 2 months back and am only active on SharePoint Stack Exchange, I did realize that having High Rep there is quite difficult but to be honest it doesn't matter because while solving a problem you learn 10 more things. 
Does gaining reputation plays any role getting a better job?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/at-what-point-do-you-put-your-so-reputation-in-your-resume

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33721/how-can-you-use-stack-overflow-and-its-sister-sites-to-advance-your-career http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29672/how-much-is-enough-reputation http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246940/how-many-stackoverflow-reputations-are-reasonable-for-getting-a-junior-developer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28938/how-much-reputation-do-you-need-to-be-worth-using-careers-stackoverflow-com http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30615/has-your-stackoverflow-reputation-helped-your-career

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think reputation should be included in your Resume because you can gain reputation in several ways. But your reputation doesn't describe your knowledge of a particular topic, your passion, your attitude facing real problems, your problem solving skills and so on.

I'll just give you an example. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable?rq=1) question on SO has been upvoted more than 1700 times, so the guy who asked that got a huge amount of reputation just for asking a simple question.

The question asked is a basic topic in Java and this guy got a lot of reputation just because he **didn't understand** such a simple thing.

So, as you can see, often reputation is not related to real knowledge you can spend to get a job.

Comment: That question is a community wiki and has been since 2012. The user has received no reputation on this question since then. Additionally, the question was created Sept 2, 2008 and the user hasn't been seen since Sept 8, 2008.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for the bad example. I'll edit the answer asap.